# Using large memory with NodeJS / IO.JS

Tags: node.js, memory-management, iojs

I'm looking at using NodeJS or IO.JS for a server app that requires a lot of RAM, 4-8GB, possibly more.

Considering the most up-to-date version of V8 and IO.JS (current is 3.3.0):

- is it realistic to implement using the latest IO.JS?
- is the platform generally suitable for such an app?
- what is the recommended approach to managing and accessing such memory from within a NodeJS process?
- any specific problems to be expected?

Please, any cons and pros using NodeJS for such an app are welcome!

Comment: You may be better off using an in-memory store such as redis that works out of process.  Then, you can store lots of stuff, without much of a loss of access speed.  Of course, this all depends also on what exactly you are trying to store in that 4-8GB which you haven't disclosed anything about.  You'd probably get more meaningful answers if you described what you're trying to do with the 4-8GB of memory.

Comment: @jfriend00 If it helps, the data is intermediate results of neural network calculations. A large image is uploaded to be processed immediately by the same upload engine, for a high-level object recognition.

Answer (score 0):

A big con would be that 64-bit Node.js applications have a memory limit of 1.4 GB. Node isn't good for large monolithic servers, it's more suited for scaling out by spawning additional processes.

Comment: Any reference for that? I thought this was an old limitation long superseded by `–max-old-space-size` or maybe something newer?